# Can a type with an implicit conversion be mapped with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, implicit-conversion

I know this works with NHibernate, but I'm new to EF code-first, and can's see how to get it done.

In short, I want to map a property on my entity `FooEntity` of type `BazCode` as though `BazCode` were a string (or `int` or `DateTime` or whatever), since `BazCode` has an implicit conversion to/from that type.

```
public class FooEntity
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string SomeText { get; set; }
    public BazCode Code { get; set; }
}

public class BazCode
{
    private readonly string _value;

    private BazCode(string s)
    {
        if(s.Length != 8)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("BazCode must be 8 characters.")
        }

        _value = s;
    }

    public static implicit operator BazCode(string s)
    {
        return new BazCode(s);
    }

    public static implicit operator string(BazCode code)
    {
        return code._value;
    }
}
```

in usage:

```
var foo = new FooEntity
{
    SomeText = "here is some text",
    Code = "A1234567"
}
```

Because `BazCode` can be implicitly cast to/from string, I can map it normally in NHibernate it just works.

With EF, the only way I see to define a mapping explicitly is to use the anonymous type constructor, but one can't use casts there, so it buys me nothing.

I am aware of the complex type concept in EF, but that isn't the same thing, so far as I can tell. I think that would require:

```
context.Foos.Where(foo => foo.BazCode.Value == "B9876543")
```

instead of

```
context.Foos.Where(foo => foo.BazCode == "B9876543")
```

This doesn't leverage the implicit conversion at all.

Is there a more sophisticated way to map entities in EF, or otherwise allow the implicit conversions?

Comment: I'm wondering how NH can deal with the last line? The `==` operator with the conversion behind is (potentially arbitrary complex) C# code. How could this in every case be translated into SQL to execute the query in the database? Or does NH somehow "parse" the content of the conversion operator and - if translatable - then translate it into SQL? For EF I'm pretty sure the last line is impossible, even if `BazCode` is a complex type. EF has ways to map entities but sadly none of them is "sophisticated". In your case I'd probably replace the `BazCode` property by a `string`.

Answer (score 3):

No. EF supports only [few basic types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399548.aspx) and complex types. No conversions are supported (EF even doesn't allow you to write the conversion explicitly). Also as mentioned by @Slauma in comment your implicit conversion will make no sense for Linq-to-entities because C# conversion logic is not translated to SQL.